# recursive bubble sort exception

Tags: java, sorting, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive bubble sort method but I get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11`. I cannot see what I did wrong.

```
    public static int[] recBubSort(int []arr, int n){
    if(n > arr.length-1){
        return arr;
    }

    if(arr[n] > arr[n+1]){
        swap(arr,n,n+1);
    }
    return recBubSort(arr,n+1);
}

   public static void swap(int arr[], int minPos, int index) {
    //System.out.println("SelectionSort SWAP...");
    int temp = arr[minPos];
    arr[minPos] = arr[index];
    arr[index] = temp;
}
```

Comment: this line     if(n > arr.length-1)
        return arr;  doesn't make sense ?!

Comment: One note though: I answered your question as is, but in fact this program will not perform bubble sort even when the error is fixed. It will just bubble one item up. Bubble sort requires *two* loops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You checked that `n` is not greater than the last allowed index (which is `length - 1`, but then in your next `if`, you ask about `arr[n+1]`.

Suppose your array has 5 items. And your `n` is 4. You checked it and it is not greater than `5-1`. But `n+1` is 5, and there is no item #5.

Comment: does the first if just checked number is greater than the length-1?

Comment: I cannot belive I missed that! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 2):

It's this line:

```
if(arr[n] > arr[n+1]){
```

You aren't checking if `n+1` is out of bounds. You only check if `n` is out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException mean **The** **index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array**. 
you can try this..

```
void bubbleSort (double  array[], int size) 
{
double temp ;
 for (int pass = 1; pass < size; pass++)    
for (int i = 0; i < size – pass; i++)
if (array [i] > array [i+1])
{
temp = array[i] ;
array[i] = array [i+1] ;
array [i+1] = temp ; 
       }
}
```

Comment: While your explanation regarding the error is good, he did not say he does not understand what this error is... you did not really try to help him with his code.